# Programatically sync OneDrive for Business folder on local machine

Tags: c#, excel-interop, onedrive

I have a spreadsheet stored on OneDrive for Business that I need to edit locally and then update online. I've got this working perfectly - by using Excel Interop I'm able to open the spreadsheet, make the required changes, save and close it, which in turn automatically syncs the changes to OneDrive.

What I can't do however is automatically sync changes from OneDrive to my spreadsheet before I open it. I can do this manually by right clicking the OneDrive for Business icon in my system tray and clicking "Sync Now". Is there a way of carrying out the "Sync Now" action programmatically?

Any help is greatly appreciated.